# Bash script for changing NVM Node version

Tags: javascript, node.js, bash, version, nvm

I'm trying to add an alias to my `.bash_profile` to do the following:

> - `xx projname` => `cd ~/folder_1/projname` and use node version
>     6 on nvm if nvm is currently using some other version
> - `yy projname` => `cd ~/folder_2/projname` and use node version 4 on nvm if nvm is currently using some other version

I have currently implemented everything except the last portion i.e. `if nvm is currently using some other version` like so:

```
function xx { cd ~/folder_1/"$1"; nvm use v6;}
function yy { cd ~/folder_2/"$1"; nvm use v4;}
```

What is the best way to handle the outstanding task? What I want is something like this:

> run `nvm current` and see if index of `v6` is false, and then run `nvm use v6`

But I'm really new to bash and can't seem to find a way to do this. TIA!

Comment: I am reading the question since I follow the bash tag, so no much knowledge of node.js. Could you indicate what is the way to check the nvm version you are running. Could it be [`nvm run node --version`](https://github.com/creationix/nvm)?

Comment: `nvm current` gives the current node version. The output is normally `v6`

`nvm use <node-version>` switches node versions

Comment: so the first word is always the nvm version? Also, does it show in stdout or stderr? You can check this saying `nvm current 2>/dev/null`. If it does show, it is stdout; otherwise, stderr.

Comment: Yeah. It does show in stdout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to get the version. From comments you say it comes like this:

```
$ nvm current
v6 <blabla>
```

So you need to catch the first word of `nvm current`'s output:

```
read version _ <<< $(nvm current)
```

Then it is a matter of comparing the value with "v6". I would use:

```
if [ "$version" == "v6" ]; then
   ...
fi
```

All together:

```
function yy {
    cd ~/folder_2/"$1"
    read version _ <<< $(nvm current)
    if [ "$version" == "v6" ]; then
        nvm use v4
    fi
}
```

Comment: That worked, thanks. I just needed to make the if condition a little wild cardy like so:

`if [[ "$version" == *"v6"* ]]; then`

Answer (score 1):

I am using this script for auto change my Node version, it works with Oh-my-zsh, make sure you have nvm installed then add below script to your .zshrc file

```
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion

autoload -U add-zsh-hook
load-nvmrc() {
    local node_version="$(nvm version)"
    local nvmrc_path="$(nvm_find_nvmrc)"

    if [ -n "$nvmrc_path" ]; then
        local nvmrc_node_version=$(nvm version "$(cat "${nvmrc_path}")")

        if [ "$nvmrc_node_version" = "N/A" ]; then
            nvm install
        elif [ "$nvmrc_node_version" != "$node_version" ]; then
            nvm use
        fi
    elif [ "$node_version" != "$(nvm version default)" ]; then
        echo "Reverting to nvm default version"
        nvm use default
    fi
}
add-zsh-hook chpwd load-nvmrc
load-nvmrc
```